# Count the child record is not work for bulkified

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to count the contact record under the particular account record. But My code is not working for bulkified.

This is my trigger coding:

```
trigger ContactTrigger_AT on Contact (before insert,after insert,after delete) {

    ContactTrigger_ATHandler contactHandler = new ContactTrigger_ATHandler();

    Set<Id> contactAccountIdSet = new Set<Id>();

    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
        for(Contact newContact : Trigger.new){
            if(newContact.AccountId != null){
                contactAccountIdSet.add(newContact.AccountId);
            }
        }
        contactHandler.addContactSet(Trigger.new, contactAccountIdSet);    
    }
}
```

This is my handler class:

```
public class ContactTrigger_ATHandler {

    map<Id,Integer> accountContactMap = new map<Id,Integer>();
    public Integer intVar;

    public void addContactSet(List<Contact> newContactList,Set<Id> contactAccountIdSet){
        for(Contact newContact : [SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN : contactAccountIdSet]){
            if(!accountContactMap.containsKey(newContact.AccountId)){
                accountContactMap.put(newContact.AccountId, 1);
            }else{
                accountContactMap.put(newContact.AccountId, accountContactMap.get(newContact.AccountId)+1);
                intVar = accountContactMap.get(newContact.AccountId);
            }
        }
        for(Contact getContact : newContactList){
            if(accountContactMap.containsKey(getContact.AccountId)){
                if(accountContactMap.get(getContact.AccountId) == 3){
                    getContact.addError('cant Add');
                }
                System.debug('map size'+ accountContactMap.get(getContact.AccountId));
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: try after insert not before

Comment: you can do this with an aggregate query

Comment: This trigger doesn't capture re-parenting (`update`) or `undelete` events.

Answer (score 0):

Count would be wrong because your map  **accountContactMap** have only count of existing contact records for each account. You should also update count for new contact records which you will get in Trigger.New.